# fetching user media from instagram api without user id

Tags: api, instagram

I did what @krisrak told me to do. I used two API calls.

One to search for the username with

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?count=1&q=USERNAME
```

and i got the user id from there to perform the second API call

The second call was

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USER-ID/media/recent/
```

This worked perfectly until I searched a certain username and I was given another. So I want to know if there's a sort of where clause to use to get the username I want from a list of results gotten. So my 1st call would now be

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?count=0&q=USERNAME
```

to enable me get all results.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no match, then that username probably does not exists, go to instagram.com/USERNAME and check if it exists. You may have to ignore and display that username does not exist.

BTW to get all the results, just remove `count=1`, then it will return a bunch of usernames that match similar search, usually the first one will be the exact match, so thats the reason `count=1` is used to match a particular username.

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=USERNAME`

Comment: The username i'm searching for actually exists but it returns another result. For instance, I searched for coltonlhaynes and it returned coltonlhaynes_fans

Comment: oh ok, I see that the match is in the second result, so use `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=USERNAME` and use a forloop and check for user.username == USERNAME, and get the id